# What is the parameter order for candlestick charts in jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jqplot, candlestick-chart

It's kind of a silly question, but I can't find the answer anywhere (and I don't really no the candlestick chart format).  In jqplot, you can make candlestick charts: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/candlestick-charts.php

For every data point, you have a length 5 array.  The first is the date.  After that there is open, close, high, low, but I don't know what order they are in.  So what is the order?

Answer (score 0):

After the date, the order is open, high, low, close.

```
ohlc = [
    // date                 // open  // hi   //lo     // close
   ['06/15/2009 16:00:00',  136,     140,    134,     138],
   ...
]
```

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dH7Hm/102/) containing a Candlestick chart with just a couple of values to demonstrate